# Grease Pencil Stuck Drawing around cursor

Tags: grease-pencil

I don't know how I did this, but for some reason every time I bust out the drawing tool, my stroke is forced to draw a circle around the cursor. Does not matter if it is a fill or a stroke.

[image: That dot in the middle is the cursor]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it turns out I didn't turn on the *Guides* button on the top of the window.

Comment: Hi, Jeremy, if you have a moment to expand on this with a screen-grab to illustrate what you mean, that would be great for others who run into the same problem.